# How do I add Tomcat 7 virtual hosting on an existing LAMP server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, port, virtualhost, web-hosting

I have a web server using the LAMP stack and it has already been setup up using virtual hosts. 
I have recently added Tomcat 7 to the server and it runs fine on port 8080.

Can someone tell me how to setup Tomcat 7 virtual hosting for a website given that virtual hosting already exists with Apache 2 on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the virtual hosting in Tomcat as well and redirect from Apache Webserver to Tomcat using mod_jk or mod_proxy. See here:

[Multiple Subdomains in Apache / Tomcat with mod_jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320286/multiple-subdomains-in-apache-tomcat-with-mod-jk/18320784#18320784)